# What's the best way to disable the default /console route in Flask debug mode?

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I want my application's dashboard area to be called /console. However, Flask uses werkzeug.debug.DebuggedApplication (http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/debug/), which uses /console as the default Debug path.  Flask itself only has the debug flag,

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

with no other options to override that path.  What are my options?

I temporarily added the following, but I'd rather not have to do that because I have some intricate thing's going on in JS on the front-end, like a redirect during registration, etc.

```
if app.debug:
  app.register_blueprint(.., url_prefix='/con')
else:
  app.register_blueprint(..., url_prefix='/console')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `use_evalex=False` in your `app.run` call to disable the console but still have reloading and the pretty Werkzeug "Don't Panic" debugger:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, use_evalex=False)
```