# Turning on LED when URL is accessed

Tags: python, bash, flask, raspberry-pi2

What I would like to do is upon the browser attempting to access my Raspberry Pi URL (http://192.168.10.191:5000/console) the LED will turn on, without needing to type any python on the front end, however at the moment, I still need to type python on the web console for it to function as intended.

Code is as follows:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

@app.route('/user')
def here():
    return '<h1>user here</h>'

@app.route('/console')
def console():
    import pexpect
    child = pexpect.spawn('python')
    child.expect('\n>>>')
    child.sendline('import os')
    child.sendline('os.system("cd /sys/class/leds/led0 && sudo sh -c \'echo 1 > brightness\' ")')
    child.expect('\n>>>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Comment: Do you mean: When accessing the URL, how to turn on the LED without inputting commands on web ?

Comment: yes,when I accessing "http://192.168.10.191:5000/console" <---my raspberry pi 2 ip address,it will execute the# cd /sys/class/leds/led0 && sudo sh -c \'echo 1 > brightness\' "  <---bash to turn pi's led on

Comment: however, right now ,I still need to type python script on the web console to turn the led on

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you want to use the `/console` URL? If you use a different one you won't have this problem.

It is used by Werkzeug by default for debugging.

You need to switch it off by setting `use_evalex=False`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21345221/whats-the-best-way-to-disable-the-default-console-route-in-flask-debug-mode) for more details.

Also you don't need to use `pexpect`. Make the call directly to `os.system`:

```
@app.route('/console')
def console():
    import os
    os.system("cd /sys/class/leds/led0 && sudo sh -c \'echo 1 > brightness\' ")

    return '<h1>changed brightness</h>'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, use_evalex=False)
```

Comment: thaks for your reply,,but I still need to type python script on the web console